# SQLAlchemy how to call stored func in batch

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to call a stored function hundreds of time in a row,
doing it in a single roundtrip to the DB would be a huge improvement,
here is what I'd like to do in pseudo code :

```
args_for_multiple_calls = [
  {"a1": 1, "a2": "dfg4"),
  {"a1": 4, "a2": "ger"),
  {"a1": 2, "a2": "sfg3"),
]

connection.executemany("select my_stored_func(:a1, :a2)")
```

Does SQLAlchemy support this ?

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy provides `executemany()` as part of [`execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute):

```
session.execute("select my_stored_func(:a1, :a2)", args_for_multiple_calls)
```

Whether `executemany()` actually supports `SELECT` queries is dependent on your driver. Also keep in mind that while this may reduce the round-trip overhead, it may still be slow due to the query execution overhead (i.e. if all your sproc does is an `INSERT` and you run your sproc 1000 times, it will be slower than a single `INSERT` with 1000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

The SQLAlchemy have no such functionality. These "low level" commands like: insert, insertmany, callproc, execute , cursor etc.. " is provided by an **DBAPI** ([Python DB API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249)) driver such as cx-Oracle, psycopg2, MySQL-Python etc... The SQLAlchemy just proxies such funcionalities provided the DBAPI driver.

If you need to execute a function you should to use the [callproc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor) cursor method:

```
args_for_multiple_calls = [
     {"a1": 1, "a2": "dfg4"),
     {"a1": 4, "a2": "ger"),
     {"a1": 2, "a2": "sfg3"),
]

conn = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for x in args_for_multiple_calls:
         cursor.callproc("my_stored_func", [x['a1'], x['a2']])
         results = list(cursor.fetchall())
         conn.commit()
   cursor.close()
finally:
   conn.close()
```

Comment: thanks, but if I have 1000 rows in args_for_multiple_calls, I will end up calling the db 1000 times right ? I want to do it in a single db roundtrip